# How do you block or scramble Wi-Fi Access?

Tags: internet, wireless-networking

I don't want to have a wi-fi signal in my apartment. I have a wired modem. But, for those tenants with a wireless modem and without a password, it is causing problems. Can I scramble the signal so it is not accessible in my apartment?

Comment: Why is it a problem if you're not using it?

Comment: Your question is quite scrambled itself so I'll guess: You want to prevent your computer to automatically connect to the wireless networks of others'? If so, then just disable your wifi.

Comment: @Debbie: Let's review: you are using a wired network connection.  Some tenants in the building are using wireless.  You can only control what's going on with the wireless signal in your apartment if you have control of the wireless access points reachable from your apartment.  If you are using a router that has wireless, disable it.  Beyond that, there's not much you can do; wireless signals from other access points are going to reach your apartment whether you like it or not.

Comment: Remove the antenna from the router.

Comment: Configure your machine to prefer wired connections over wireless.  Then you can leave on connecting to open servers without using them when connected to wired.

Comment: @boot13: You should post that as an answer.  However, you do have some control over signals within your space even if they originate elsewhere: you could cover your walls with foil left over after you made your hat. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the tenants don't have a password, they should not be able to connect, if you disable the wireless part or if you set up your wireless part to require a password.

If you don't want your router to broadcast its presence, you can disable SSID broadcast. Here is some more information: http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessproducts/qt/disablessidcast.htm

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the wireless part of your router you should be able to go to the configuration page and disable it.

The exact steps will depend on the router. Check your manual or search online for your router make and model to download the instructions.